# How can I automatically download a .csv file from a hyperlink in a GMAIL message and add its contents to a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api, gmail

I receive an email with a hyperlink that when clicked starts a download of a csv file to my Gmail account. It's not an actual attachment. When I receive this email (which has a unique subject line), I need a way to automatically add the contents of the downloaded .csv

Trigger:
An email with a specific subject line is received to my gmail account

Action 1:
Download a .csv file from a hyperlink within the body of the email

Action 2: 
Add the contents of the .csv file to a Google Sheet file

I need an already built service that does this or suggestions on how to approach it.

If I can get this Google script to run, I should be able to find a working solution. The problem is the script keeps giving me errors.

```
function downloadFile(fileURL,folder) {

  var fileName = "";
  var fileSize = 0;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  var rc = response.getResponseCode();

  if (rc == 200) {
    var fileBlob = response.getBlob()
    var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folder);
    if (folder != null) {
      var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
      fileName = file.getName();
      fileSize = file.getSize();
    }
  }

  var fileInfo = { "rc":rc, "fileName":fileName, "fileSize":fileSize };
  return fileInfo;
}
```

Comment: I tried connecting with a Zapier integration, but the solutions provided are not sufficient. There are a few scripts that attempt this with an actual attachment, but I'm struggling with this being a hyperlink download. I feel like this should actually be easier, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: I've also tried the instructions here with no luck: https://ctrlq.org/code/20053-save-gmail-to-google-spreadsheet

Comment: @PaulJump Why did you unaccept this answer? Does this suffice for you?

Answer (score 2):

This is something I recently tackled at work, fully automating data pulls from my emails to a database. I am not going to write a solution for you, but I will provide you with the information and links you need to do it yourself.

**Note**: Your question is very broad, and covers a large range of different problems, each of which should be tackled one at a time with their own question (Many of which already have multiple answers on StackOverflow). This is a process to follow with linked documentation, and a couple code snippets so you can do it yourself and tackle each problem along the way.

The Proposed Process:

1. Open the email with the [GmailApp Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)
2. Extract the link via the script below
3. Get the CSV from the link via the code linked below. This utilizes `UrlFetchAp`, the `Blob` datatype, and the `parseCsv` utility (which you have to escape commas first, because it's buggy)
4. Modify the contents of the resulting array to your liking
5. Use the [SpreadsheetApp Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to open a spreadsheet and get a range
6. Set the values of that range to your array of data.

**Extract href link from email (assumes only 1 link):**

```js
//Retrieves a URL from a HTML string from an href. Only applicable if there is only one link in the string
function GetHrefURLsFromString(string){
  var href = string.match(/href="([^"]*)/)[1];
  if(href){
    return href;
  } else {
    throw "No URL Found"
  } 
}
```

**Extract CSV from link:**

```js
//Gets a CSV from a provided link, and parses it.
function GetCSVFromLink(link){
  var urlData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link);
  if(urlData.getBlob().getContentType() == 'csv'){
    var stringData = urlData.getContentText();
    var escapedStringData = stringData.replace(/(?=["'])(?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]\r\n(?:\\[\s\S][^'\\]\r\n)*')/g, '\r\n');
    var CSV = Utilities.parseCsv(escapedStringData);
    return CSV;    
  }
  Logger.log('DataType Not CSV')
  return null;
}
```